# research internship visa in france for PhD student with no master's degree?

Tags: research-process, visa, france

I am a PhD student in Chile, now in my 3rd/4 years. I have been awarded an international internship funding by my scholarship agreement (provided by the chilean government). I have an invitation of a laboratory in Paris, expected to start just before 2024 begins, and lasting **9 months**.

The visa options I found require me to hold at least a master's diploma or equivalent, which sadly I don't have (https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/passeport-talents). However, it's worth saying that I hold a "Mathematical Engineering" diploma in Chile, whose duration is a minimum of **6 years** for obtention, which is longer than european undergrad programs, I read.

What is my best shot for obtaining a visa for this internship? do you think I can say/prove that my chilean engineer title is equivalent to a master in europe?

I guess people at the center where I plan to go could help, but have been a bit difficult to reach.

Thanks!

Comment: There are internship visas of course, not sure why you are looking at a migration visa like the Passeport Talents. Check https://www.campusfrance.org/en/long-stay-internship-visa